# Symfony2 Can't inherit abstract function Validator\ValidatorInterface::validate() (previously declared abstract in \Validator\ValidatorInterface)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

If I use the symfony console command `generate:doctrine:crud` with `--write` parameter I get an auto-generated controller working only in the `indexAction` route, but not in the others (`newAction`, `deleteAction`, `updateAction`). I think the problem is in the form creation. 
The resulting error is the following one:

> Compile Error: Can't inherit abstract function
>   Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface::validate() (previously
>   declared abstract in
>   Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface)
>
> Server Error - FatalErrorException500 Internal in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveValidator.php at line 31

I don't know, how to solve this problem.

Comment: same here. Still searching for solution.

Comment: which version of php are you using?

Comment: PHP Version => 5.4.42. 
The only working solution was change the symfony framework ValidatorInterface interface file:

Comment: I've got the same problem with php 5.3 and it was solved when I upgraded my php version to 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this problem is to change ValidatorInterface or to run almost PHP 5.6

Answer (score 4):

This error is the error message you get when running the new validator component in PHP 5.3.8 or older. You need to use at least PHP 5.3.9 to use recent versions of Symfony